# Source map generated by webpack works, but can't debug properly

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm new to Webpack and React. I'm building an app using react, and today tried to create a build for the first time (i'm using create-react-app).
When trying to debug using Chrome dev tools, I can see all my Components using the map file generated by webpack/babel, however I get an error when placing a breakpoint inside a basic map method, and trying to access the value of the current item, or the mobx store items.
It's obviously working fine in development mode.

I guess i'm missing something with the configuration?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: I have faced this issue many times and in such cases, mostly variables are accessible as "varName_1". Can you try writing "image" in the console, wait and see what completion suggestions chrome provides? It will give you a better idea.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Currently fixed it by setting mangle=false in the uglify plugin. This causes uglify to not change variable names, so the map file has no problem to map to the real variables.